# No Windows Phone Emulator in Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, emulation, hyper-v

I have an issue : I don't have any Windows Phone Emulator that appears in my Visual Studio while i have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I read that WP SDK is included in VS Ultimate 2013, but there is no emulators proposed when i want to debug my application. There is only 'Device'. So I tried to install the WP SDK. So now I have a VS Express for Windows Phone Edition and when I want to try to debug with an emulator, there isn't any.

And my computer support Hyper-V and Hyper-V is enabled. I don't understand what is the origin of my issue?

Thanks for any help

Alexandre D.

Comment: What Visual Studio updates do you have installed.  Do you also have the Windows Phone SDK update installed?  There are updates for the Phone VMs

Comment: Can you start the Hyper-V manager and see emulators registered there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes I can start the Hyper-V manager but I don't see any emulators registered...

Comment: I managed to launch a WP emulator in command line but no integration in Visual Studio...strange...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution : after installing the Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC, it works perfectly.

Here the link for the download : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307

Thanks for your help guys